# Smarter way to isolate a value in an unformated string?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) in an AIR app to convert PDFs to PNGs on the fly. Before conversion I want to get a page count and am using xdf's [pdfinfo](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfinfo1.html) utility to print to `stdout` and then parsing that string to get the page count.

My first pass solution: split the string by line breaks, test the resulting array for the "Pages:" string, etc.

My solution works but it feels clunky and fragile. I thought about replacing all the double spaces, doing a split on ":" and building a hash table – but there are timestamps with colons in the string which would screw that up.

Is there a better or smarter way to do this?

```
    protected function processPDFinfo(data:String):void
    {
        var pageCount:Number = 0;

        var tmp:Array = data.split("\n");

        for (var i:int = 0; i < tmp.length; i++){
            var tmpStr:String = tmp[i];

            if (tmpStr.indexOf("Pages:") != -1){
                var tmpSub:Array = tmpStr.split(":");
                if (tmpSub.length){
                    pageCount = Number(tmpSub[tmpSub.length - 1]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        trace("pageCount", pageCount);
    }
```

---

```
Title:          Developing Native Extensions  
Subject:        Adobe Flash Platform  
Author:         Adobe Systems Incorporated  
Creator:        FrameMaker 8.0  
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller Server 8.1.0 
CreationDate:   Mon Dec  7 05:45:39 2015  
ModDate:        Mon Dec  7 05:45:39 2015  
Tagged:         yes  
Form:           none  
Pages:          140  
Encrypted:      no  
Page size:      612 x 783 pts (rotated 0 degrees)  
File size:      2505564 bytes  
Optimized:      yes  
PDF version:    1.4
```

Comment: Speaking of clunkiness, why not do the pdf parsing in As3? Without throwing strings around over `stdout` you would not have the problem in the first place.

Comment: @null – ? I am using the `pdftopng` functionality of `xpdf`. This is just to get the number of pages through `pdfinfo`. But if you would like to share AS3 code for parsing PDFs, I would be happy to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) like this one for example:

```
/Pages:\s*(\d+)/g
```

The first (and only) capturing group is the string of digits you are looking for.

```
var pattern:RegExp = /Pages:\s*(\d+)/g;
var pageCount:int = parseInt(patern.exec(data)[1]);
```

---

> I understand about 2% of that (/Pages: /g). It is looking for the string literal `Pages:` and and then something with `spaces wildcard` and `escaping d+`??

I know, regex can be hard. What really helps creating them is if your IDE supports them. There are also online tools like [regexr](http://regexr.com) (me first time using version 2 here and it's even better than version 1, very nice!) In general, you want to have a tool that gives you **immediate visual feedback** of what's being matched.

Below is a screenshot with your text and my pattern in regexr.

[image: regexr in action]

You can hover over things and get all kinds of information.
The sidebar to the left is a full fledged documentation on regex.

The optional *explain* tab goes through the given pattern step by step.

`\s*` is any amount of whitespace characters and `\d+` is at least one numeric digit character.

> and returning an array??

This is the As3 part of the story. Once you create a `RegExp` object with he pattern, you can use [`exec()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#exec%28%29) to execute it on some `String`. (not sure why they picked the retarded abbreviation for the method name)

The return value is a little funky:

> Returns
>
> Object — If there is no match, `null`; otherwise, an object with the following properties:
>
> - An array, in which element 0 contains the complete matching substring, and **other elements of the array (1 through n) contain substrings that match parenthetical groups in the regular expression**
> - `index` — The character position of the matched substring within the string
> - `input` — The string (str)

You have to check the documentation of `exec()` to really understand this. It's kind of JS style, returning a bunch of variables held together in a generic object that also acts as an array.

This is where the `[1]` in my example code comes from.

Comment: @1202ProgramAlarm sorry for the confusion, added some more info